# ProxyRemote for Proxypass

Tags: apache, webserver, devops

I want to check my logic with you experts to check if it is correct.

**What do I want to do?**

Requests to Location search of suggest are send to Proxypass.
Proxypass connection is passed through the proxy  with the Proxy Remote directive

- Will that eventually work?
- How can see if the proxy is being used?

> ```
> ProxyRemote "https://website.com/query/search/" "http://proxy.com:8080"
> ProxyRemote "https://website.com/query/suggest/" "http://proxy.com:8080"
>
>  
> <Location "/search">
>     RequestHeader set Auth-Key "test"
>     ProxyPass https://website.com/query/search/
> </Location>
>
> <Location "/suggest">
>     RequestHeader set Auth-Key "test"
>     ProxyPass https://website/query/suggest/
> </Location>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `LogLevel proxy:trace5` above the ProxyRemote entries.

Then check the apache2 logs (usually /var/log/apache2/access_log) for `[proxy:...]` entries: specifically look for `[...] connecting https://website.com/[...] to website.com:443`.

Don't forget to remove the LogLevel entry again, proxy:trace5 is pretty verbose.